# Get current module flavor name from another module with no flavor

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I have 2 separate modules in my app : `main` and `core`.

In `main` I have different flavors

```
productFlavors {
    fla1 { }
    fla2 { }
}
```

In `core` I have no flavor but I have a deeplink builder. This builder is used in `main`.

Question: Is there a way for `core` deeplink builder to return the flavor name of `main` where it is being called?

Note: As the name suggest module `main` depends on `core`

Answer (score 0):

If `core` knows about `main` flavor it is said that core is depends on main. So you can't.

Just pass flavor name from main.

Or create another "flavor" module that just define flavor and depends to it.
"flavor" module will have same flavor with "main"'s one. (Don't say it is no longer "core" :))

```
main -> core -> flavor
```